# Why web page consumes a constant 18% of the CPU

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

I'm working on a landing page for my brother's new website, but I faced a wired issue that I have no idea how to approach.

On a Windows 10 machine, Nothing else was going on in the machine, the page consumes more than 15 percent of the CPU (Core i 7 3.4 GH).

Below is a more detailed display of CPU usage from the task manager of windows. It hovered around 18%, sometimes spiking as high as 25%. Other than Chrome itself, the computer was doing nothing but displaying the page. I wasn't even scrolling the page.

The Chrome browser has its own Task Manager (Hamburger menu -> More tools -> Task manager) which showed that "page" tab consuming 39% of the processor.

Any Idea what causes the problem?

Comment: Look at Chrome's dev tools

Comment: I wouldn't say that page is doing "nothing." There's a whole lot going on there.

Comment: @Robert Harvey What do you mean? those animations?

Comment: Yes.  Those animations.

Comment: :') that's a ****ton of animation, it even takes a couple of seconds to load.

Comment: What do you recommend... do I need to remove all the animations or I can keep some? Do those animations cause taking too long to load?

Comment: Is the utilization really even a problem?  Your clients' computers will still function.

Comment: I can hear my laptops fan ! So yes the performance is a problem for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how much is being used by

1. a new tab page
2. an empty index.html
3. some other website

Namely, percentage tells you little, because it's relative to that machine.

If an empty index.html is using for example 15% to your 18% then your page isn't really using much, but rather the computer is slow (slow or overburdened with spyware or bottlenecked in RAM or whatever or perhaps you have a lot of extension), and just the browser itself is "overloading" it.

Past that, not enough information from your question, it can't be determined by just a screenshot. As others have suggested, dev-tools is the place for such inspection, tab performance.

Edit: oh, now I've noticed the link. Yeah, those animations :')

---

Here's a somewhat organized idea on how to optimize:

1. Remove all animations. (Comment them out.) If little difference, abort, problem is somewhere else.
2. If at least some notable difference, profile several times, like get an average of 3 refreshes and / or closing of browser (hard quit if on mac). For purest result, make sure no other tabs are running including extensions, hidden chrome windows etc. If you're extra serious, profile on several browsers as well, if not, at least check Firefox or whatever, maybe it's only on Chrome. (And that's valuable info. Perhaps it's memory bottlenecking, so your processor needs to write in and out much more often. Not sure. Don't guess.)
3. Mind your enviroment. Check if the problem persist if you build for production. (If you're using such steps.)
4. Mind the way you're doing the anim. Javascript? Check out best practices, very easy to botch. JQuery? There are more safegurads, but still, check best practices. CSS? Best place to do anims. (Did I mention best practices?)
5. Comment in single animation, one by one. Find the highest offender (the highest difference). See if you can rewrite the highest offender better first.
6. See if you can group animations, ie. rewriting couples. See if you're defining several animations for different places, but could instead refactor it so instead it's one anim for many uses.
7. If still a problem, start cutting out anims weighing which cost the most in performance vs. which you find most important for your design.

Cheers and best of luck

Comment: I have a quad-core machine running at 4ghz, and my utilization is about 12%.

Comment: Also worth noting, my GPU utilization is about 62%.

Comment: What do you recomment to remove ?... my performance check in chrome dev tools has not finished...

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the page that overload your processor, check it with Inspect and see from the sources, performace and memory why it is consuming so much.